# Get Objects which their parents have some criteria - Yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have an object Author, an object Post and an object Comment. **`Comment`** BELONGS_TO **`Post`** and **`Post`** BELONGS_TO **`Author`**.

I want to get all Comments which the Post created after the `'01-02-2015'` AND Author's **birthday** is after `01-01-1980`.

How can I develop  condition/criteria for these rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Comment extends CActiveRecord {
   public function search(){
      $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
      $criteria->together = true;
      $criteria->with = array(
          'post' => array(
              'condition' => "created>='2015-02-01'",
              'joinType' => "INNER JOIN",
              'with' => array(
                  'author' => array(
                      'condition' => "birthday>='1980-01-01'",
                      'joinType' => "INNER JOIN",
                  )
              )
          )
      );

      return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
          'criteria' => $criteria
      ));
   }
}
```